# Achieving more accurate geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, geolocation

Currently, I am using Google Maps API with HTML5 geolocation to create a POC about asset tracking via a web service. The user opens the web browser and we track it from there and display it on an admin map. I have been testing it out and the results are not great. A sample picture of my commute to work is below:

[image: HTML 5 geolocation]

As can be seen, the dots are scattered all over the train tracks and not very accurate. I am trying to make it so that it is very accurate, within 10m of the actual position. Having done some research, HTML5 Geolocation is not that great, and I have read about using Apache Cordova/ Phonegap and native geolocation off the phone with google maps for more accuracy. Can someone verify that this is the case?

Eventually, we are planning on a native app, but for now, it is web based,but if I can make a strong enough pitch, we might go to a hybrid until native app dev is done.

In terms of what my setup is, I use navigator.getCurrentPostion() to get the initial position and then run watchPosition with an update to the DB every 30s. Both are set to high accuracy mode, but the results do not indicate this.

EDIT: took a look at Google's geolocation off of their site, and here are the results :

[image: Google Maps Site vs geolocation]

Comment: If you open google maps in the browser does the blue dot track appear more accurately than your dots?

Comment: Took a look and the location is noticeably better than what I have. I have included an example diagram in the OP.

Comment: Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions


These might also help

- http://www.andygup.net/how-accurate-is-html5-geolocation-really-part-2-mobile-web/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202077/high-accuracy-geolocation-html5